# Is Kylo Ren more force capable than Snoke?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

Kylo Ren used force to remotely turn and activate Luke's lightsaber and cut Snoke in halves.

- It has been stated over and over again, Snoke can read others' mind and feelings, how could Snoke not see Kylo's move?

Is Kylo so force-capable that he could hide his true feelings from Snoke?

Comment: I think we don't know yet. IMO TLJ  set up a series of ruse, where it's very unlclear what the end games are for several characters and/whom is reallymanipulating whom. Most notably Snoke, Kylo Ren, & DJ don't give clear instances of true motives, but unresolved ones. A lot of people think just because Snoke ----, means he isn't important, which I think is a premature conclusion, especially since Rey's role seemingly as a 'nobody' was so pronounced and because of how the mythology advanced with Force Ghosts...

Comment: It was all word play, "I see you will strike down your hated enemy" or something like that - well, he did and it was Snoke.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Kylo Ren is a very strong force user.  Luke says something to the effect to Rey:

> I wasn't frightened enough when I came across such power the first time

We also see him perform other 'tricks' that have never been seen in Star Wars before, like stopping a blaster bolt in mid air for more than a minute.

However I don't think we've seen what the powers of Snoke are, so cannot judge whether he or Kylo Ren are more capable.

The key thing we see is that Kylo Ren disguises his feelings about what he is about to do.  You can see Snoke (apparently) reading Kylo's mind - repeating out loud that he is turning the lightsabre and is about to kill his target.  Kylo does this acting out turning the lightsabre in his hands as he stands in front of Rey, while turning the sabre to the side of Snoke with the Force.

He is gambling that Snoke's attention is on what he is seeing in front of him.  He is gambling that Snoke will assume the feelings he is reading relate to Rey's imminent death, and overlooks the possibility that his apprentice is planning to kill him.

So its not that Kylo is *so* strong with the Force that he can disguise his thoughts completely.  He uses his powers and misdirection to achieve his aims.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Snoke can read mind. Well at least not just by looking at them. Information retrival shown by Kylo on Rey or Poe in The Force Awakens, seemed a bit more involving than staring. Even Snoke needed to hold Rey still a second before.

Snoke ability was more like emotion and intention reading. If I remember correctly Snoke said that Kylo will strike his enemy which was correct. That is exactly what Kylo did, but Snoke was mistaken when he thought about Rey, because Kylo considered Snoke to be his great enemy at that time.

So answering your question directly, I don't think Kylo is more powerful than Snoke when it comes to Force manipulation. Snoke read his intentions correctly, he just didn't realize the whole truth.